# Chromium rebuild error

Tags: chromium

After running command

```
ninja -C out\Default chrome
```

Got and errors:

```
    c:\src\chromium\src\base\strings\pattern.cc: 
        fatal error C1853: 'obj/base/base_cc.pch' header file is from a previous  of the compiler,  the precompiled header is C++ and you are using it from C (or vice versa)
            [11/1486] CXX obj/cc/paint/paint/precompile.cc.obj
            ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
```

Any idea how to fix?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the same issue, due to an upset of semi-installs. I solved it by doing a full clean of the build (and learning to use some ninja in the process).

Run the following

```
ninja -C out/Default -t clean
```

and then rerun

```
ninja -C out/Default Chrome
```

Mine worked after this.

Comment: maybe you know how to fix https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!msg/chromium-dev/jnofouwbn0k/9lD-x-6LAgAJ this one?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `GN` to clean the build folder too:

```
gn clean out\Default
```

Then rebuild again:

```
ninja -C out\Default chrome
```